# Saving Y-m-d to Datetime to DateTimeImmutable field in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to save Y-m-d date format to field date

```
#[ORM\Column]
private ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at = null;
```

When I save this formatted date:

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable();
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Symfony saves with the following format:

```
2023-01-17 14:34:55
```

When I try to save a date like this:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

I get an error:

```
must be of type DateTimeImmutable, string given
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that play a role here:

1: your entity expects an `DateTimeImmutable` Object, but you provide a `string`. Thus to solve this, use The `DateTimeImmutable` object to create and pass the correct object type your method asks for.

2: You want to save your date in a specific format, Y-m-d. To do that, change your ORM\Column type to `date` instead of `dateTime`

If you want to use `Y-m-d` format in your project, use the correct formatting to achieve that.

Take a look at the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/types.html#date-and-time-types)  for deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

To save the date in Y-m-d Format, you can use createFromFormat method

`$date = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", date("Y-m-d", $timestamp));`

I hope it will solve your problem. Let me know if you have any question

Comment: Thank you but still saves like 2023-01-17 15:10:23

Comment: To make sure the date is saved in the format "Y-m-d" when you save it to the database, you need to change the date from an object to a string and make sure the column in the database table where you are saving the date is a date datatype or varchar.